# Binding the content of a label with a checkbox in MS Access 13

Tags: data-binding, checkbox, label, ms-access-2013

I was using MS-Access-13 to make a data entry form. I need to link the content of a label to a check-box, if the check-box is ticked/checked the content of the label should be "enrolled" else the content of the label must me "awaiting confirmation".Is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a label but a text box (delete the automatic label that comes with the textbox) and have the textbox formatted as a label (transparent color, center justify, font and color scheme whatever) to align to other labels.

Then, put in its Control Source whatever conditional formula you need:

```
=IIF([Checkbox]=True, "Enrolled", "Awaiting Confirmation")
```

By the way, you can have the Checkbox derive from other forms but to reference it you must have the form opened in background.

```
=IIF(Forms!OtherForm!Checkbox=True, "Enrolled", "Awaiting Confirmation")
```

Comment: Thanks Worked like a charm!

Comment: Great! Can you select my answer?